# Version comparison tool

Tags: apex, visualforce, knowledge, articles

Can anyone please give me an idea on how to create visualforce page for comparing two versions of an article in salesforce.

PS- It should work like a diffchecker tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would leverage a 3rd party JavaScript library for this. Pick one from these search results https://www.google.com/search?q=diff+javascript. Your Visualforce then only needs to display the two articles and call the JavaScript that will present the differences.